# Iterate through the columns of a dataframe in Python and show value counts for the categorical variavles

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to Python and programming, so this is no doubt a newbie question.  I want to show the value counts for each unique value of each categorical variable in a data frame, but what I've written isn't working.  I'm trying to avoid writing separate lines for each individual column if I can help it.

| # | Column | Non-Null Count | Dtype |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | checking_balance | 1000 non-null | category |
| 1 | months_loan_duration | 1000 non-null | int64 |
| 2 | credit_history | 1000 non-null | category |
| 3 | purpose | 1000 non-null | category |
| 4 | amount | 1000 non-null | int64 |
| 5 | savings_balance | 1000 non-null | category |
| 6 | employment_duration | 1000 non-null | category |
| 7 | percent_of_income | 1000 non-null | int64 |
| 8 | years_at_residence | 1000 non-null | int64 |
| 9 | age | 1000 non-null | int64 |
| 10 | other_credit | 1000 non-null | category |
| 11 | housing | 1000 non-null | category |
| 12 | existing_loans_count | 1000 non-null | int64 |
| 13 | job | 1000 non-null | category |
| 14 | dependents | 1000 non-null | int64 |
| 15 | phone | 1000 non-null | category |
| 16 | default | 1000 non-null | category |

Code I've written:

```
for col in creditData.columns:
    if creditData[col].dtype == 'category':
        print(creditData[col].value_counts())
```

The results:

```
unknown       394
< 0 DM        274
1 - 200 DM    269
> 200 DM       63
Name: checking_balance, dtype: int64

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-6a53236835fc> in <module>
      1 for col in creditData.columns: # Loop through all columns in the dataframe
----> 2         if creditData[col].dtype == 'category':
      3                 print(creditData[col].value_counts())

TypeError: data type 'category' not understood
```

Comment: try changing ```if creditData[col].dtype == 'category':``` to ```if creditData[col].dtypes == 'object':```? or ```if creditData[col].dtype == 'O':```

Comment: This should work. There is also something strange with your output. It succeeded running it on the first column which is category

Comment: I tried both 'object' and '0', and neither of those worked.  Strangely, when I tried `if creditData[col].dtype != "int64":`, that returned only the categorical variables.  But obviously that's not ideal if I have a data frame with more variable types than just category and int64.

Answer (score 1):

this works for me

```py
for i in creditData.columns:
    if creditData[i].dtype != 'int64':
        print(creditData[i].value_counts())
```